# Proftp error message Fatal: unknown configuration directive 'DisplayFirstChdir' on line 22 of '/etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf'

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp, proftpd

Sorry for the newb factor but I'm trying to set up a server using this guide:

http://www.intac.net/build-your-own-server/

I'm at the end of step 5 and when I try to restart proftp I get the following error message

```
me@me-desktop:~$ sudo service proftpd restart
 * Stopping ftp server proftpd                                                                       [ OK ] 
 * Starting ftp server proftpd
 Fatal: unknown configuration directive 'DisplayFirstChdir' on line 22 of '/etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf'
                                                                                                     [fail]
```

Any clues on how to change line 22?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [DisplayFirstChdir](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_DisplayFirstChdir.html) directive is deprecated. Comment it out and try again.

Comment: Thanks sir, shall I comment out the following code?
`<Directory>
    #DenyAll
    TransferRate        RETR 50
    <Limit WRITE>
      DenyAll
    </Limit>
  </Directory>`

Comment: This code make your ftp server is read-only. Also comment it out if you want to allow your users to upload. There's no need to find HOWTO anywhere, just read the [document](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Directory.html) in the homepage first.

Comment: For any other readers: `DisplayFirstChdir` was deprecated, and *replaced with* [`DisplayChdir`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/modules/mod_core.html#DisplayChdir).